# Zakat on annual savings

Tags: sharia, zakat, money

I started paying zakat last year, 2012. In it I paid $2,500 zakat on a $10,000 saving. This year, 2013, my savings have increased to $12,000.

Should I now pay zakat on $12,000 or only the net increase in savings i.e. $2,000?

Comment: zakat is always for wealth "not used" within that past 12 months... in your case: 12000 is the base for zakat calculation... Allah knows best.

Comment: If in 2012 you paid $2500, that works out at 25%. Zakaat is 2.5%

Answer (score 1):

Zakat is due on the entirety of your savings, so long as they have maintained at least the *nisab* for an entire year.  So in your case — and this is according to the Hanafi madh'hab — you would owe zakat for the whole $12,000 (which at 2.5% works out to $300).